# What game is this? (First-person character holding an orange mass labeled "Paleberry")

Tags: game-identification

[image: Picture of game I found]

I found this picture on a discord server and I was wondering what it was.

Comment: This is definitely Satisfactory, I play it.  But it might be a older/unreleased version I am not familiar with, or modded. I do not recognize the two upper displays on the left and the UI does not have rounded corners like it has normally.

Comment: Definitely using the PowerSuit Modules mod (https://ficsit.app/mod/7J2LyFzTakqPQ5). Also running a recent build of the game (the full-height windows were added in Update 5 a few weeks ago). The only thing missing is the Early Access string and build number on the top left (the game is currently in Early Access, but it could also show "Experimental" for the bleeding-edge build)

Answer (score 29):

That appears to be the game [Satisfactory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfactory)

[image: Satisfactory]

<sub>This image is from Brendan Caldwell's review of the game at https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/satisfactory-review-early-access</sub>

I found it by searching “[Paleberry](https://satisfactory.fandom.com/wiki/Paleberry)”, and Satisfactory was the first thing that came up.

Comment: Looks modded. 'Biofuel Suit' and whatever that thing is in hotkey 7 are not in the base game.

Comment: This screenshot also says "Early Access" in top left.

Comment: @Nelson That's normal, Satisfactory screenshots always say either Early Access or Experimental in the corner unless a mod removes that text.